# Using API how to find the parent branch in Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I want to find the parent branches for a particular branch. Suppose I have created A branch from master and branch B from A. Now I want to find the parents for B like B->A->Master. I checked the Bitbucket API but there is no such a method available. When I pull the data for a branch there is no field which shows the parent branch details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular `git` commands for that:

```
git branch --merged HEAD --sort=authordate
```

This lists the ancestor branches of the current working directory in chronological order (you can of course specify any other ref instead of `HEAD`) and would be great to use in a script or some automated tooling.

A very quick and dirty alternative way would be to just look at the regular output of `git log`:

```
git log --graph --decorate | egrep 'commit .* \('
```

This variation would maybe be interesting for a human to watch but too noisy for a script.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply AnoE. I am writing Python script, now need to find how can I implement this in Python.

Comment: You'll find out for sure - you can just run commands from this as system/shell commands or subprocesses; the output from the first command is dead simple and easy to parse.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think there is any module which will allow me to execute this git command in the python.